# Rule of "most of something"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I have following construction.

> Although *most of the RTGs* **work rely** on external sub-graphs, they
>   are not able to represent every incidence.

*Here RTG stands for Roof Topology Graph (RTGs plural case)*

I am confused with the rule of most of xxx and doubted that whether it should be corrected as or not

> Although *most of the RTGs* **work relies** on external sub-graphs, they
>   are not able to represent every incidence.

any comments please.

Comment: I'm a little unclear here how you're using "work." Are you trying to say that "most of the work done on/with/for RTGs relies on external sub-graphs, ..." or are you saying that RTGs working (that is, functioning) relies on ..." ? I mean, either way, it looks like it should be "relies," but I think the "s" in RTGs is is tripping me up.

Comment: @pmusser: yes, i am telling first thing you mentioned. but, as far as I know, with most of the noun should be a plural for e.g. most of my friends... so then?

Comment: Aha, okay. I'll answer the question below, but I think here you'd drop the S because you're using the graphs to define the "class" or "type" of work being done, but you aren't discussing particular graphs. If this is unclear, I think it would TOTALLY warrant a new question that I think you should ask! :D

Comment: I think there is a possession issue. Does the work belong to multiple RTGs? (`Although most of the RTGs' work...`) Or does it belong to one RTG? (`Although most of the RTG's work...`)

Comment: @Tamara: it is RTGs... then can you correct me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you'd definitely say "relies" and not "rely." The subject of the verb "to rely" here is "work," which corresponds with "relies." Consider the following:

> My work relies on lots of different people providing me with what I need.

Here, "work" is a singular noun that is a placeholder for whatever it is that I do. In contrast:

> My parents rely on me to wire money home every two weeks, so that they can pay the bills.

Two parents, so plural noun. Plural noun means plural conjugation for "to rely." Therefore, "my parents rely on me ..."

Comment: Exactly. So the correct construction is `Although most of the **RTGs'** work **relies** on external sub-graphs, they are not able to represent every incidence.` Note the possessive form of "RTGs" (with the apostrophe).